# Disable/Enable widget in Magento 2 admin

Tags: magento2

I need to enable and disable a widget from time to time in admin. I don't see a disable/enable switch please advise how it can be done.

Answer (score 3):

Yes,*Magento does not have feature for disabled/enabled for  Widget module*.

So, the **only solution is that delete those widgets which you have created if want to disable those widget**.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I guess I'm gonna have to settle for that :(

Answer (score 2):

I had the same requirement. I achieved it by deleting the layout updates selections.

[image]

If the widget is not being instructed to show up anywhere then, even though you have it in Admin Panel, it wont show up in your site.

Comment: I think that it is better deleting widget for performance issues.